# Rails 3 popup window on link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have link that naviates to certain controller and action: 
    <%= link_to "Detail", {:action=> 'detail', :id=> person.id}   %>

I want this window to be a popup window, do some changes there and after some controller action finishes e.g. action Save, I want to close this popup window. In earlier versions of Rails this was done bu :popup=> true which is already deprecated. How to do it in Rails3?

Answer (score 1):

This is the quick and dirty solution.

```
<%= link_to "Detail", {:action=> 'detail', :id=> person.id}, :onclick => "javascript:window.open('page.html','popup','width=400,height=200');" %>
```

If you're loading jQuery you can be more eloquent and unobtrusive, or use something like this:

http://www.openhosting.co.uk/articles/webdev/5918/

Hope that helps.